# resizing Photoshop brush dynamically with alt + right click not displaying properly

Tags: adobe-photoshop

There's a *fantastic* hidden gem in Photoshop allowing you to resize the brush tool dynamically by selecting the tool and right clicking while holding down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.  Vertical mouse movement changes brush diameter; horizontal mouse movement changes brush hardness.

It should display a red rendering of what the brush will become, but sometimes I don't see the red (just a circle), and it becomes impossible to guess what the brush will become simply by observing the UI widget's numerical values.  Anyone aware of a setting that will make this feature display the red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Edit then Preferences then under Performance make sure Use Graphics Processor is selected. While there click on Advanced Settings and make sure Use OpenCL is select as well. You'll need to restart photoshop for it to take effect. And this of course assumes you have a capable graphics card.

If either of those are turned off you won't get the red visual you're referring to.

[image]

Comment: Bullseye.  And by coincidence, I got a graphics processor error launching Photoshop this morning.  Thanks.